# A unital ring of characteristic zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Context: Let R be a unital ring. The characteristic of R is the smallest positive integer n such that n⋅1=0. If no such n exists, we say R has characteristic 0. We denote the characteristic of a ring by char(R).

Question: Every unital ring of characteristic zero is infinite (I'm thinking of using a proof by contradiction for this, but I have no idea how).

Could you provide an answer that **avoids** using **group theory** since I haven't even learned about it yet and I understand it even worse than I understand ring theory? Also, the fact that this question is probably so basic shows my lack of understanding of ring theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $R$ is unital, you know it has a $1$. Since it has character $0$, you know that $1$, $1+1$, $1+1+1$, etc. are all distinct elements.

If you prefer proofs by contradiction, if the ring were finite, then by pigeonhole we must have $\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_n = \underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_m$ for some $n \not = m$. Without loss of generality, $n > m$, and so 
$\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n-m} = 0$, and $R$ has character $n-m$.

---

Hope this helps ^_^

Comment: You mean for distinct $n$ and $m$ right?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor thanks for the concise answer

Comment: @HallaSurvivor, why must there be distinct $n$ and $m$ such that $n\cdot 1=m\cdot 1$? Is it because there are more natural numbers than elements in $R$ if $R$ is finite?

Comment: Exactly! It's the pigeonhole principle - if you try to put infinitely many pigeons into finitely many holes, one of your holes has multiple pigeons.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{n\cdot 1 \,:\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset R$ has an infinite amount of distinct elements. To see this, suppose that there are two distinct natural numbers $m,n$, such that:
$$m\cdot 1=n\cdot 1$$
Then as we are talking about a Ring $R$ we have that:
$$(m-n)\cdot 1=0$$ 
And thus the characteristic is finite, contradiciting the assumption.